# Slickgrid 2.1 - Apply and Remove Formatters On The Fly (i.e., Depending on Runtime Conditions)

Tags: slickgrid, formatter

I'm using slickgrid 2.1 and successfully using a formatter for one of my columns in order to display a button that, when clicked, deletes the corresponding row from the grid.

My requirements and question: I need to only display this button in the row the user single-clicks on.  When the user clicks one row, then another, the button from the first selected row needs to be hidden and the button on the second selected row needs to be displayed.  How can I programmatically do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you share, what code did you try so far?